# Manejo de excepciones en angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Como implementar una clase externa de manejo de excepiones y no hacerla de la siguiente forma y no repertirlas en los diferentes servicios.
Para que los `alert` se visualizado por el cliente.

```ts
 return this.http.get(this.config.apiEndpoint + 'Values')
            .map(response => <person[]>response.json())
            .catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status === 500) {
                    alert('Error 500');
                }
                else if (error.status === 400) {
                    alert('Error 400');;
                }
                else if (error.status === 409) {
                    alert('Error 409');;
                }
                else if (error.status === 406) {
                    alert('Error 406');;
                }
            });
```

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: No nada,  he intentado usar una clase por aparte (es decir un archivo por aparte) refereciarla dentro catch no me ha funcionado. - Juan Hernández

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente yo tengo las funciones de manejar los errores y de capturar los datos en un servicio que injecto en los componentes u otros servicios segun lo demande. Las funciones son estas:

.- Trycachear los errores:

```
public handleError (error: Response | any) {

let errMsg: string;
let errorCode:number;
if(!environment.production){
  console.log("(handleError) Error Arrojado:");
  console.log(error);      
}
if (error instanceof Response) {
  const body = error.json() || '';
  const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
  errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  errorCode = +error.status;
} else {
  errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
}      
if(!environment.production)console.error(errMsg);
this._helper.notificationToast(errMsg,"Error","error");
if(errorCode===401){
    this._router.navigate(['salir']);
}
return Observable.throw(errMsg);
```

}

.- Para extraer los datos utilizo:

```
public extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();


if(!environment.production&&environment.depurar){      
  if(body.error){
    console.log("(extractData) Body Error:");
    console.log(body.error);
  }
}

//Actualizar token
if(body.token!=null){
  // if(!environment.production){console.log("Token actualizado: "+body.token)}
  this.token=body.token;
}

//Si ha habido un error lanzar mensaje
if(body.error){
  this._helper.notificationToast(body.error,"Error","error");
}

if(body.success&&!body.data){
    var data = {success:true, message:body.success}; 
    body.data=data;
}

return body.data || { };
```

}

y justo así es implementado en otro servicio (Obtener un perfil de usuario):

```
getPerfil(perfilId:string): Observable<Perfil> {
    let _headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._autenticacionService.token });
    let _options = new RequestOptions({ headers: _headers });
    return this._http.get(environment.api_url+'/seguridad.php/perfil/'+perfilId, _options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return this._helperService.extractData(response);
        })
        ._catch(err=>this._helperService.handleError(err))
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien lo que usted esta busacando es [`ErrorHandler`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html)

Podria queda algo asi:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

 handleHTTPError(res:Response){
     //Tratar error aqui
     throw new Error("error HTTP : "+ res.statusText +" ("+ res.status +")");
 }

}
@NgModule({
    providers: [{
                provide: ErrorHandler,
                useClass: MyErrorHandler
                }]
})
export class MyErrorModule {}
```

En su app.module

```
import { MyErrorHandler } from "./error.-module"; <- donde lo tenga
import { MyErrorModule } from "./error.-module";  <- donde lo tenga

//..

@NgModule({
           imports: [ MyErrorModule
           //..
           ],

           //..
           providers: [MyErrorHandler]

           //..
```

---

```
return this.http.get(this.config.apiEndpoint + 'Values')
            .map(response => <person[]>response.json())
            .catch((res)=>this.handleHTTPError(res));
            });
```

P.D: *No tengo mucha experiencia en Angular2, y no se si esta es la mejor manera para manejar esta situacion, como angular2 esta cambiando por ejemplo antes se llamaba `ExceptionHandler` y no se si habran cambiado muchos detalles para usarlo ect.*